# How can you modify express.res within bluebird promises, and use res within another promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bluebird

I might be overthinking this, but bear with me... If I have the following code

```
app.get('/api/endpoint', function(req, res, next) {
    new Promise(function() {
        // doing something that takes lots of code
        return someJson
    })
    .then(function(someJson) {
        // analyze someJson with lots of code
    })
    .then(function() {
        // do more
    })
    // chain a bunch more promises here
    .then(function() {
        res.status(200).send(message)
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        // error handling
    })
    .finally(function() {
        // clean up
    })
})
```

If the promise chain gets very long, it can be a pain to navigate the endpoint. So, I want each step of the promise to be it's own function (to simplify the above code). So I can rewrite the top 2 promises as so:

```
function findSomeJson() {
    return new Promise(function() {
        // doing something that takes lots of code
        return someJson
    })
}

function analyzeSomeJson(someJson) {
    return new Promise(function(someJson) {
        // analyze someJson with lots of code
    })
}
```

Now, each of these functions can be used in the original example like so:

```
findSomeJson()
.then(function(someJson) {
    return analyzeSomeJson(someJson)
})
// etc...
```

But, what happens if I need to tweak `res` within those promises? Do I need to return `res` every time and store someJson within res? And, what happens if I have to use next()? How do I ensure `res` is modified at the end of my promise chain? I can't do that in `finally()`, do I have to do it in my last promise?

Comment: What is a `private function`?

Comment: Closures to the rescue!

Comment: Private wasn't needed. Removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to be able to mutate `res` from within your functions you have to pass it around. I think the easiest/cleanest way to pass it around is to use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) like this:

```
findSomeJson()
  .then(analyzeSomeJson.bind(this, res))
  .then(doMore.bind(this, res))
  .then(andEvenMore.bind(this, res))...
```

Then the `analyzeSomeJson` definition would look like this:

```
// .bind makes it so that res is the first argument when it is called
function analyzeSomeJson(res, someJson) {
  return new Promise(function(someJson) {
    // analyze someJson with lots of code
  })
}
```

But I would probably try to avoid passing around `res` so that only your controller has to know about `req` and `res`. You could move all your functions to a service or services and have the controller determine what needs to happen to `res` based on what the service(s) return. Hopefully that will lead to maintainable/testable code.

**UPDATE** very simple service example

```
// endpoint.js
var jsonService = require('./jsonService.js');

app.get('/api/endpoint', function(req, res, next) {
  jsonService.getJson()
  // chain a bunch more promises here
  .then(function(json) {
    if(json === null) {
      return res.status(404).send('Not Found');
    }
    res.status(200).send(json);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
      // error handling
  });
});
```

There are many ways you could implement your service but really its just another .js file that you require in to your "controller" or endpoint.js. Whatever you export will be your "public" methods.

```
// jsonService.js

// "public" methods
var service = {
  getJson: function() {
    return findSomeJson().then(analyzeSomeJson);
  }
};

module.exports = service;

// "private" methods
function findSomeJson() {
  return new Promise(function() {
      // doing something that takes lots of code
      return someJson
  });
}

function analyzeSomeJson(someJson) {
  return new Promise(function(someJson) {
      // analyze someJson with lots of code
  });
}
```

Comment: +1                                                                                           for recommending to keep `req`/`res` out of those functions

Comment: Sorry, do you have an example (or link) of this? I haven't used the service pattern yet (and if I have, I haven't called it that).

Comment: @Matt I just updated the answer with a simple service example.

Comment: Thanks. So you'd pass all the data you need for the entire promise chain into `jsonService.getJson(allTheData)`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly by `allTheData`, but yes, if you are getting data from the request I would pass that to `jsonService.getJson(req.params.userId, req.body)` instead of passing `req`  or `res`

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. Can't update my previous comment though. Thanks.